# Use a CDN to access Firebase Storage objects through their Download URL?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have image files in Firebase Storage what have Download URLs.  I can access these just fine through the Download URLs.

I have set up a Google Cloud Platform CDN to point at my Firebase Storage bucket.  When I try to access images in the bucket, I get an **Access denied.** response.

The instructions for setting up a GCP CDN pointed to a Bucket say to use the format:
`https://[IP_ADDRESS]/static/[REGION]/[OBJECT_NAME]`

I used the external load balancer IP Address, "us" for the region, and I have tried several things for [object_name].

The image file Object has a Download URL that looks like this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxx.appspot.com/o/-LmBkDlSNaSqtFI8AfFX%2Ffoo%2Fbar_-LmDYUM32YieXcpjm7jR.png?alt=media&token=61E4F4A8-99BF-495E-89F0-03BB565D0D8A
```

So, I tried using everything after `/o/` as [object_name]
I tried the storage location path.
I tried URL encoding the slashes in both of these.

In all cases, I get the following:

```xml
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access denied.</Message>
    <Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to buttons-dev.appspot.com/static/us/-LmBkDlSNaSqtFI8AfFH/circles/circle_-LmDYUM32YieTcpjm7jR.png.
</Details>
</Error>
```

The permissions in Firebase Storage for the bucket are set to:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

But, the Download URL should work for direct viewing of a particular file.
Also, I tried setting `allow: read;` for permissions, and nothing changed.

How can I access a Firebase Storage object in through it's Download URL and a Google Cloud Platform CDN?

Comment: Security rules are bypassed when using download URLs or other direct access URLs.  Rules only matter when the access is coming from the Firebase SDK.

Comment: Yup!  I get that.  So, is it possible to have the Google Cloud Platform CDN cache content that is accessed through Download URLs?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to change the behavior of a download URL obtained by the Firebase SDKs, other than to revoke its access.

Comment: I am not trying to change the behavior.  I want to use the GCP CDN to cache it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That's effectively a change in behavior (the behavior being the caching).  I don't think you can simply reroute that URL to go through any other CDN or cache system.  The URL is what it is - direct access to the underlying object in Storage.

Comment: Maybe my question was too literal.  I have a Firebase application where users can upload photos, and I'd like access to those photos to be cached.  Sounds like using a token and the Download URL functionality does not fit my use case?  Is the use of a CDN not possible in conjunction with Firebase Storage Rules?  Do I need to just make all images public to get browser caching and CDN delivery?

Comment: I don't believe that using a download URL suits your case.  Security rules have no effect on the way anything might be cached.

Comment: Please know that I do appreciate your replies!  Do you have a suggestion for my use case?  Are Firebase Storage Rules *and* browser caching possible?

Comment: Rules have nothing to do with caching. They are only about access control

Answer (score 2):

The process is -

1. Setup a load balancer and enable CDN for it
2. Allow public access to the images you want to access via CDN or to the entire bucket. Instructions for it are in this link -
   https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public
3. If you have a file in Firebase storage named `foo/bar/image.png`

   then access it simply with `http://[LOAD_BALANCER_IP_ADDRESS]/foo/bar/image.png`

In your example, this will work

`http://[LOAD_BALANCER_IP_ADDRESS]/-LmBkDlSNaSqtFI8AfFX%2Ffoo%2Fbar_-LmDYUM32YieXcpjm7jR.png`

The base URL depends on what you have setup in Host and path rules. If you have only one backend setup then the above will work as-is.

Complete guide - https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-backend-buckets-to-load-balancers